# How to limit a Git branch name to 50 characters

Tags: git, groovy, jira, git-branch, scriptrunner-for-jira

I am currently trying to make a script using groovy to implement as a Pre-Hook for Jira using ScriptRunner. The script is supposed to block branch if they are more than 50 characteres long. I am new to Grrovy and stack overflow and i am quite lost.

```
def branchName = currentBuild.rawBuild.getEnvironment(listener).get('GIT_BRANCH')
def branchNameLength = branchName.length()
def branchNameLimit = 50

if (branchNameLength > branchNameLimit) {
error("branch name too long; limited at: ${branchNameLimit} characteres. Actual name lenght: ${branchNameLength} caracteres.")
}
```

This is the code I did but it doesn't seems to work, do you have any tips or solution to help resolve this problem?

I tried doing it using a RegEx but I failed too. What I want is to limit the number of characteres whenever you try to create a branch.

Comment: Git has no such restriction and does not invoke any hooks when you create a branch. You can't stop anyone from using any name they like in their own *local* repository; the only place you can do this thing is in a repository where you have control.

Comment: Are you sure you mean Pre-Hook for Jira and not Pre-Hook for Bitbucket? Jira does not manage any git repositories, but Bitbucket does. Also, where do you got that script from? That looks like it was written for Jenkins and not for ScriptRunner for Bitbucket.